# OAuth 2.0 Google Sign in and non Google APIs calls

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I just started web developpment and currently I'm making a simple HTML page with JavaScript.

The page needs data from this API : 
https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://ao-docs.appspot.com/_ah/api#p/search/v1/search.search.searchDocuments

And it requires OAuth 2.0 protocol for authorization and sign in with a Google account, so I followed https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent on OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Web Applications but I can only use Google's APIs and not the one above.

I am beginner on all these API stuff and I'm looking for indications please.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT : I juste realised I'm getting a error on the discovery URL.

var discoveryUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/search/v1/rest';

[here is an image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KVm5.png)

Comment: Did you specify the scope value required for this API ? I think it require https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email scope value to for your access token

Comment: Also it's good to specify the error you are getting

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I did specify the right scope value for this API.
Also i just realised that the error I'm getting is because the discoveryUrl is wrong.
I edited my post with clarifications.